# Change the size of the "insert vertex" crosshairs in QGIS when digitizing polygons

Tags: qgis

I'm digitizing some drainage basins in QGIS. A major annoyance I've had when delineating basins in QGIS is that the crosshairs for adding a new vertex to an existing polygon is extremely small and often difficult to see. I would like to increase the size to something that stands out a bit more. Is this possible to change in QGIS?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go to Menu <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Options</kbd> > <kbd>Digitizing</kbd> tab > expand the entry <kbd>Vertex Markers</kbd> and change the <kbd>Marker size</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: Hi Babel, that only works for existing vertices. It doesn't change the size of the "insert vertex" crosshair.